# Plugin 'Fig' (version 2.0.0) was explicitly marked as incompatible with the current version of the IDE

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, fig

I tried to uninstall Fig plugin from WebStorm many times, but each time I open my IDE this pop up comes back. How can I get rid of it?

Additionally, the following error message pops in my IDE regularly:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot invoke (class=FigWindowListener, method=toolWindowsRegistered, topic=tool window events)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.kt:677)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.deliverMessage(MessageBusImpl.kt:423)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.pumpWaiting(MessageBusImpl.kt:402)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.access$pumpWaiting(MessageBusImpl.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.kt:461)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy73.toolWindowsRegistered(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$postEntryProcessing$2.invokeSuspend(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:177)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$postEntryProcessing$2.invoke(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$postEntryProcessing$2.invoke(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span$default(tracer.kt:49)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.postEntryProcessing(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:176)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.postEntryProcessing$default(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:174)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.createAndLayoutToolWindows(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:157)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer.access$createAndLayoutToolWindows(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.toolWindow.ToolWindowSetInitializer$createAndLayoutToolWindows$1.invokeSuspend(ToolWindowSetInitializer.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.RuntimeExceptionWithAttachments: Access is allowed from Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) only; see https://jb.gg/ij-platform-threading for details
Current thread: Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-53,5,main] 1709490363 (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false)
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] 1722986913
```

Comment: Do the following: 1) Close WebStorm 2) Go to the plugins folder -- check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#plugins-directory. NOTE: if you are using Toolbox App to install your JetBrains IDEs, the settings folder *might be* in a bit different place (seen it a few times in the past). In such a case check `idea.log` file -- at the start of each IDE session it writes the paths used. 3) Locate and delete the plugin file (or folder) manually. 4) Launch the IDE and check again.

Comment: I can't find anything related to fig there:


➜  plugins ls
IdeaVim                           intellij-rainbow-brackets
Key-Promoter-X                    jetbrains-extension-2.0.0
StringManipulation                mdx
WakaTime.jar                      ml-llm
clouds-docker-gateway             pomodoro
github-copilot-intellij           reactbuddy
graphql                           sonarlint-intellij
grazie-pro                        space
idea-php-dotenv-plugin-2023.3.jar tailwind-formatter-next
ideolog                           wallaby-intellij
➜  plugins

Comment: Do you have Fig app installed? Did you had Fig plugin installed in the past (the app may have installed it for you right into the IDE plugins folder) or even right now? So far I have found these: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-329754 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-328086 . If you have the plugin on your Plugins screen -- try just disabling it and restart the IDE -- any better?

Comment: On a second though --- `jetbrains-extension-2.0.0` -- this MIGHT BE the one. I'm basing this guess by the crappy description of the plugin that I see for Fig on those screenshots. If it's the one -- do not delete it straight away but move it to another folder and confirm that it is gone first (in case I'm wrong and it's some valid/proper working plugin)

Comment: Yes I still have and use the app. The plugin was installed with an early version. I ignored the pop up for a long time. But it became annoying on the long run.

I was going to say that I already uninstalled the plugin. But it keep coming back from the dead. I tried the command line `➜ fig integrations uninstall intellij` which prompted me `Warning: IntelliJ integrations are automatically reinstalled on launch
Uninstalled!`

Let's see if that cures the problem for good. But the error message indicates the opposite.

Comment: If uninstalling does not work -- try just disabling it then. *In theory* it should prevent that message since the plugin is not active (but who knows what conditions are used when checking for incompatibility...)

Comment: I disabled it many many times, but it keeps coming back. I still have the issue to this day